# Setting up DHCP server - fail to start/stop it

Tags: server, 14.04, dhcp, cluster

I am following [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EasyUbuntuClustering/UbuntuKerrighedClusterGuide).
I am completely new to Ubuntu, working on 14.04 LTS.

When I reach the last step before dealing with Kerrighed (half way through the tutorial), I try to start my DHCP server but it fails.

```
root@MASTER:~# /etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa restart
root@MASTER:~# /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart
 * Stopping ISC DHCP server dhcpd                                                 [fail] 
 * Starting ISC DHCP server dhcpd                                                         * check syslog for diagnostics.
                                                                                  [fail]
root@MASTER:~# /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
 * Stopping NFS kernel daemon                                                     [ OK ] 
 * Unexporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                               [ OK ] 
 * Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                                 [ OK ] 
 * Starting NFS kernel daemon                                                     [ OK ] 
root@MASTER:~#
```

Here is what I got in syslog by typing dmesg :

```
[18103.047124] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
[18104.195774] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
[18104.195797] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net ffffffff81cda240)
root@MASTER:~#
```

And syslog :

```
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd: Wrote 0 deleted host decls to leases file.
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd: Wrote 0 new dynamic host decls to leases file.
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd: 
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd: No subnet declaration for eth0 (no IPv4 addresses).
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd: 
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd: 
Jul 17 17:16:11 MASTER dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Jul 17 17:16:17 MASTER rpc.mountd[24387]: Caught signal 15, un-registering and exiting.
Jul 17 17:16:17 MASTER kernel: [22896.481789] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
Jul 17 17:16:19 MASTER kernel: [22897.636160] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
Jul 17 17:16:19 MASTER kernel: [22897.636192] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net ffffffff81cda240)
Jul 17 17:16:19 MASTER rpc.mountd[24820]: Version 1.2.8 starting
```

Here is /etc/dhcp/dhcp.config :

```
# General options
option dhcp-max-message-size 2048;
use-host-decl-names on;
deny unknown-clients; # This will stop any non-node machines from appearing on the cluster network.
deny bootp;

# DNS settings
option domain-name "kerrighed";          # Just an example name - call it whatever you want.
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;  # The server's IP address, manually configured earlier.

# Information about the network setup
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option routers 192.168.1.1;              # Server IP as above.
  option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;  # Broadcast address for your network.
}

# Declaring IP addresses for nodes and PXE info
group {
  filename "pxelinux.0";                 # PXE bootloader. Path is relative to /var/lib/tftpboot
  option root-path "192.168.1.1:/nfsroot/kerrighed";  # Location of the bootable filesystem on NFS server

  host M4500_1 {
        fixed-address 192.168.1.101;          # IP address for the first node, kerrighednode1 for example.
        hardware ethernet XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX;  # MAC address of the node's ethernet adapter
  }


  server-name "kerrighedserver"; # Name of the server. Call it whatever you like.
  next-server 192.168.1.1;       # Server IP, as above.
}
```

(The MAC adress is the correct one in the file)

Here is etc/network/interfaces :

```
# The loopback interface:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
# The primary network interface, manually configured to protect NFS:
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The connected slave computer (for the clustering) says `PXE-E51 : No DHCP or proxyDHCP offers were received`. Therefore it looks like the DHCP server is definitiely not runing. Tftpd does not give any answer when i restart it in the terminal and nfs looks good though.

Comment: `dmesg` is not the same as `/var/log/syslog`, although there are overlaps.

Comment: can you post your /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf ?

Comment: could you post your /etc/network/interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check:

-> /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server contains INTERFACES="eth0" ?

-> be sure if you're using /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf, and not /etc/dhcp/dhcp.config  (as you're using isc-dhcp-server)

->Define the group and its contained host into the subnet { } declaration